# Drive different elements of a structure from different modules

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to debug an error which got me to this question. Is it legal to drive different elements of a structure from different modules or would it give Invalid Driver Error

For example, is this legal? If it is not, how else would I achieve the same functionality. (The code is not syntactically correct but it conveys what I am trying to say)

```
module top()
{
 struct x; //has elements a,b,c

 x.a = 10;

 module A1(input x)
 module A2(output x)

}

module A1()
{

  return x.a & x.b;

}

module A2()
{

   x.b = 20;

 }
```

Comment: The example code is C like. Looks nothing live Verilog or SystemVerilog. Structs do not exist in Verilog, they do in SystemVerilog. Components of a struct can be driven from separate modules.

Comment: You can do this provided that each filed has a single driver and also you use the right complete hierarchical name in each module. Alternatively, you can drive separate output ports in modules A1 and A2, and then connect those output ports to `x` fields in the top module. This is preferred IMO since you would avoid using hierarchical names in your design.

Comment: I guess driving separate ports and connecting them later is a good solution. How would I use hierarchical names though, like top. x.a and top.x.b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for structs are the same for integral bit vectors. You can drive independent selects of them depending on how they are declared as wires or variables. Wires can have multiple continuous drivers, and variables can have a single continuous driver, or multiple procedural assignment. Note that a port can only have one type and one direction associated with that type, and is considered a continuous assignment in the direction of the port. You can't have different members of a struct going in different directions.